# Dynamic table doesn't fit in bootstrap card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have datatables inside of bootstrap cards, but when the table is larger than the height of the card, it will exceed outside of the card. I have an overflow: auto on a table-wrapper which also does not trigger once exceeding the cards height.

heres a simplified example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bootstrap4-gbnhfx?file=style.css

Comment: you have to wrap it in a height controlled container e.g. `<div class="table-wrap">
                  <div style="height: 690px">
                    <table class="table table-sm table-dark table-striped">`
ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bootstrap4-tsnbuq

Comment: you should paging your content instead of trying to fit

Comment: I agree with @HienNguyen, if you have a lot of rows scrolling can be a pain, and you should consider paginating your data into the card, but if you 'only just' have too many maybe a scroll is easier/better - you know your data better...

Comment: Pagination is a great idea but it's not an option since I'm just following orders, it would only be 2 pages anyway, so I don't think the scroll will be much of a pain. Also @developer your sollution didn't do the trick sadly, I'm trying not to work with fixed heights.

Comment: Can you give more details about why it didnt work please?  It worked in the stackblitz, in respect of what you had already added.  Can you provide more detail, to see if i can help?

Comment: because I didn't want to give it a fixed height

Comment: You should really put your code IN your question, though putting it in a sample place like stackblitz can be a help also.

Answer (score 0):

I've forked you stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bootstrap4-tsnbuq)

I've used a style attr here for simplicity.  But the inner div is the item being overflowed, and then your outer div (which you have CSS which handles overflow) is adding scroll.

Here is the main change:

```
<div class="table-wrap">
  <div style="height:690px">
    <table class="table table-sm table-dark table-striped">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```